# Eliminar registro con Sweetalert

Tags: php, sweetalert, eliminar

Estuve leyendo posteos, pero todos hablan de AJAX, que jamás he usado y desconozco.

Tengo una tabla, con una imagen que representa la opción ELIMINAR. Mi objetivo es que el usuario toque en la misma y se abra un Sweetalert donde el usuario elija por SÍ o por NO.

Tengo el código para eliminarlo en otro archivo PHP, pero no se cómo tomar el ID de la fila a eliminar para utilizarlo en Sweetalert. Desconozco.

**Código que uso en la imagen ELIMINAR (pensaba usar modal también):**

```
<a href="" data-toggle="modal"> <img src="../imagenes/eliminar.ico" name="eliminar_usuario" onclick="usuario_eliminar_confirmar('<?php echo $usuarios ['id_usuario'] ?>')"></a>
```

**Código del Sweetalert que advierte de la eliminación:**

```
function usuario_eliminar_confirmar(id) {

Swal.fire({
    icon: 'warning',
    title: '¿Estás seguro/a de eliminar a este/a usuario/a?',
    showConfirmButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'ELIMINAR',
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    showCancelButton: true,
    cancelButtonText: 'CANCELAR',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    buttonsStyling: true,   

}).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../head_menu/usuarios_eliminar.php',
            data: 'id',
            success: function(data) {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: 'Usuario eliminado correctamente',
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 1500,
                })
            }
        });
    }
})}
```

**Código para eliminar en BD (lo modifiqué mil ves):**

```
<?php
        include("../conexsesion/conexion.php");

        $usuario_id=$_POST['id'];

        $sql="DELETE from usuarios WHERE id_usuario='$usuario_id'";

        echo $eliminar=mysqli_query($acceso,$sql);
?>
```

Ahora sí... llegué hasta el alerta de eliminar o no...

Comment: Implementa el confirm dialog de sweetalert que hay aqui y ya esta: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#confirm-dialog   Con eso no creo que te haga falta ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo tu codigo modificado:

Solo te agrege la variable *id* a tu ajax poque vi que estas enviando es un string mas no una variable

```
    function usuario_eliminar_confirmar(id) {
    
    Swal.fire({
        icon: 'warning',
        title: '¿Estás seguro/a de eliminar a este/a usuario/a?',
        showConfirmButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'ELIMINAR',
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonText: 'CANCELAR',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        buttonsStyling: true,   
    
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../head_menu/usuarios_eliminar.php',
                data: {id:id},
                success: function(data) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: 'Usuario eliminado correctamente',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 1500,
                    })
                }
            });
        }

})}
```

En tu PHP para validar si se inserto o no puedes usar un estado

```
<?php
        include("../conexsesion/conexion.php");

        $usuario_id=$_POST['id'];

        $sql="DELETE from usuarios WHERE id_usuario='$usuario_id'";

        if (mysqli_query($acceso,$sql) === TRUE){
            echo 1;
            }
            else{
             echo 2;
            }
?>
```

Te dejo la documentación oficial de *mysql_query* para que puedas investigar más

> **https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php**

y tu *ajax* dentro de tu **Sweetalert** quedaría algo así

-Validas el numero que te devuelve tu php para saber que mensaje mostrar

```
       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../head_menu/usuarios_eliminar.php',
            data: {id:id},
            success: function(data) {

                if (data==1) 
                {
                 Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: 'Usuario eliminado correctamente',
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 1500,
                })                      
                }
                else
                {
                  Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Usuario no se pudo eliminar',
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 1500,
                    })                      
                }


            }
        });
```

Comment: @JoseuVargas Gracias por tu gran ayuda! Tengo estos problemas: si elimino desde success: function(data) {}, aparece el Sweetalert y elimina la fila. Pero si lo dejo, no me lo elimina... ¿qué puede ser?

Comment: *Pero si lo dejo, no me lo elimina*... que es lo que dejas?

Comment: Te pido disculpas, de tanto que modifiqué, tenía errores en los símbolos. Me funciona perfecto tu código, más que agradecido. Solo quería consultarte cómo puedo mostrar un mensaje de error cuando no se produce la eliminación del registro? success: function(data) { } es para cuando se cumple, pero fail: function(data) { } es para cuando no funciona?

Comment: Te entiendo, dejame y modifico la respuesta y te coloco en caso de error

Comment: Era más simple de lo que leía jaja Hice la prueba y funcionan ambos casos. GRACIAS es poco!!! Me hiciste animar a usar AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Hay un par de cosas que no estas haciendo. La primera es que al evento click estas llamando correctamente la función, pero tu función no recibe parámetros, hay que corregir

```
function usuario_eliminar_confirmar( id ) {
```

Después tienes que invocar la llamada de AJAX, puedo ver tu HTML y tiene bootstrap, por lo que daré por hecho que usas Jquery, así quedaría la llamada

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'usuario/eliminar/' + id,
     method: 'DELETE',
     success: function( data ) {
     Swal.fire({
       icon: 'success',
       title: 'Usuario eliminado correctamente',
       showConfirmButton: false,
       timer: 1500,
      })
     }
});
```

Si te das cuenta, debes tener un sistema basado en API como recomendación, la `url` es el endpoint a donde ajax hará la petición, y el `method` es el verbo que se utilizará en tu endpoint para hacer distintas acciones sobre un mismo recurso (En este caso **usuarios**)

El código luciría así mas o menos

```
function usuario_eliminar_confirmar( id ) {

    Swal.fire({
        icon: 'warning',
        title: '¿Estás seguro/a de eliminar a este/a usuario/a?',
        showConfirmButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'ELIMINAR',
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonText: 'CANCELAR',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        buttonsStyling: true,
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'usuario/eliminar/' + id,
                method: 'DELETE',
                success: function( data ) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: 'Usuario eliminado correctamente',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 1500,
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    })
}
```

Te comparto la filosofía básica de [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: No logro hacerlo funcionar. Seguí leyendo, modificando y solo funciona hasta el alerta de confirmar si se elimina o no. Verás que estuve buscando por otras preguntas realizadas acá. Voy interpretando AJAX de a poco...